# Which system modules are on the module path by default?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, module-path

When I run an application via `java -cp` (without `--add-modules` or `--limit-modules`), some Java system modules are observable while the others are not.

For example, all `java.se` modules are observable. All `java.se.ee` modules are not observable. I know that `javafx.*` modules are observable. `jdk.unsupported` and `jdk.shell` are observable too.

So, is my assumption correct: if no `--add-modules` and `--limit-modules` are specified, the set of observable system modules consists of all system modules except `java.se.ee`?

Is there a reliable way to know the exact list of default observable system modules? I know there is a `--list-modules` option, but it lists all modules including `java.se.ee`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So, is my assumption correct: if no --add-modules and --limit-modules are specified, the set of observable system modules consists of all system modules except java.se.ee?

In short, yes that is correct.

The default set of modules enabled in Java 9 are known as the **root modules**. 
Per [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261), the default set of **root modules** are defined as:

> - The java.se module is a root, if it exists. If it does not exist then every java.* module on the upgrade module path or among the system modules that exports at least one package, without qualification, is a root.
> - Every non-java.* module on the upgrade module path or among the system modules that exports at least one package, without qualification, is also a root.

Here is a nice graphic of what is included in the `java.se` module:
[image]
(Source: [Java 9 javadoc](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.se-summary.html))

Like the `java.se` aggregate module, the `java.se.ee` module itself does not provide any classes, it is an aggregate module that includes the following modules:

```
java.se
java.activation
java.annotations.common
java.corba
java.transaction
java.xml.bind
java.xml.ws
```

---

> Is there a reliable way to know the exact list of default observable system modules? I know there is a --list-modules option, but it lists all modules including java.se.ee.

Your terminology is slightly off here. In Java 9 a module is *observable* if both of the following are true:

- the module is a system module (i.e. comes from the JDK) OR it is added to the module path
- the module is not excluded via `--limit-modules`

This means `java.se.ee` is *observable* by default.

I think instead you are wondering *what modules are the default set of **root modules***? In which case, see the above definition of root modules.

Comment: "The default set of modules enabled in Java 9 are the ones included in the java.se aggregate module" - so why doesn't the runtime fail when I use `sun.misc.Unsafe`? `Unsafe` is certainly not in the java.se module graph.

Comment: Good point, the `Unsafe` class is in the `jdk.unsupported` module which is required by the `java.corba`, `java.xml.bind`, and `java.xml.ws` modules, so I thought it would only be pulled in if you add one of these modules.  Now that I'm re-reading JEP 261, I was missing this part: _". Every non-java.* module on the upgrade module path or among the system modules that exports at least one package, without qualification, is also a root."_ which means that `jdk.unsupported` would also be a root module by default.  Updating my answer now

Comment: @AndyGuibert The image link is broken in the answer.

Comment: @nullpointer thanks for the heads up.  I just tested all of the links after reading your comment and they all appear to be working for me.  What link is broken for you?

Comment: How can I determine the actual default set of root modules from the command line? Or even better, how can I determine which JRE modules are not in the default set? I am looking for some examples of JRE classes for which I would actually need `--add-modules` when compiling a non-modular application.