# When running mvn test why is build failing with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.http.HttpResponse?

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

When running `mvn test -e -X` why is build failing with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.http.HttpResponse?

I am using java 17
My stack trace is:

```
Running job testJava17ClientSamples ...
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
[1mApache Maven 3.9.5 (57804ffe001d7215b5e7bcb531cf83df38f93546)[m
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /usr/local/jdk-17.0.9
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-1053-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[0m[0mApache Maven 3.9.5 (57804ffe001d7215b5e7bcb531cf83df38f93546)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /usr/local/jdk-17.0.9
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-1053-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
...
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< org.openapijsonschematools:petstore >-----------------
[INFO] Building petstore 0.0.1
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
...
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/net/http/HttpResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3402)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive (Class.java:3543)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0 (Class.java:3529)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2225)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly (JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test (JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept (JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept (JUnit4TestChecker.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses (DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.scanClassPath (JUnitCoreProvider.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.getSuitesAsList (JUnitCoreProvider.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.getSuites (JUnitCoreProvider.java:102)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeGetter (ReflectionUtils.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.getSuites (ProviderFactory.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.getSuitesIterator (ForkStarter.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet (ForkStarter.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.http.HttpResponse
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatedClassLoader.java:97)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3402)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive (Class.java:3543)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0 (Class.java:3529)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2225)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly (JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test (JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept (JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept (JUnit4TestChecker.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses (DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.scanClassPath (JUnitCoreProvider.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.getSuitesAsList (JUnitCoreProvider.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.getSuites (JUnitCoreProvider.java:102)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeGetter (ReflectionUtils.java:69)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.getSuites (ProviderFactory.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.getSuitesIterator (ForkStarter.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet (ForkStarter.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openapijsonschematools</groupId>
    <artifactId>petstore</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>petstore</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <url>https://github.com/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator</url>
    <description>OpenAPI Java</description>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator</url>
    </scm>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Unlicense</name>
            <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>OpenAPI-Generator Contributors</name>
            <email>team@openapijsonschematools.org</email>
            <organization>OpenAPITools.org</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://openapijsonschematools.org</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <compilerArgs combine.children="append">
                        <arg>-Awarns</arg>
                        <arg>-J-Xss4m</arg><!-- Compiling the generated JSON.java file may require larger stack size. -->
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
                            <version>${checker-version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>2.2.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>loggerPath</name>
                            <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- attach test jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add_sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add_test_sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <doclint>none</doclint>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- @Nullable annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
            <version>${checker-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
            <version>${checker-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <checker-version>3.42.0</checker-version>
        <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
        <junit-version>4.13.2</junit-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

java.net.http is literally built into the standard library. Why is it not being found?
How do I fix this?

Build and testing works on my local machine when run from intelij using build project and run configuration

My PR with this issue is here:
https://github.com/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator/pull/391
CircleCI run with trace:
https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator/3712/workflows/733c1f49-de14-4887-a5ba-a9d5b3318601/jobs/17623

Failing step:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project petstore: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null: java/net/http/HttpResponse: java.net.http.HttpResponse -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project petstore: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

Comment: The `java.net.http` module should be a root by default when compiling/running code in the unnamed module. See [Which system modules are on the module path by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44051223/).

Comment: Are you sure the *tests* are running on Java 17? Looking at that stack trace, none of the frames include a module name, which should be there at least for the standard library methods if the Java run-time is version 9 or later (though note the HTTP Client API was added in version 11). It is also potentially weird that this exception is being thrown by a `URLClassLoader`, as none of the built-in class loaders are an instance of that class since Java 9, but that could be due to how Maven/JUnit/whatever loads the test classes. In short, make sure your tests are not running on Java 8 (or older).

Comment: I output the maven info and it shows Java 17

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I believe that's only saying which Java version Maven is running on, not _necessarily_ which version is running the tests. And I still found that stack trace strange.

Comment: Though I'm now realizing [the logs](https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator/3712/workflows/733c1f49-de14-4887-a5ba-a9d5b3318601/jobs/17623) claim no tests were even run; this error seems to be coming from the surefire plugin itself. I also notice you are using version `2.12` of that plugin. That's a very old version. What if you upgrade to the latest version, which as of this comment is `3.2.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by the maven-surefile plugin being out of date. When When the below updates are made to pom.xml, `mvn test` passes:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>loggerPath</name>
                            <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I find it prudent as a rule of thumb to always specify a version for whatever plugins are being used in your POM.  Else you're at the behest of whatever Maven decides to pull in depending on the JVM version actually being used.